# attempt to re-open an already-closed object sqlite

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I am using Android Room 1.0.0 for DB. While running the app I get following error.

```
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/user/0/com.abc.mypkg/databases/myapp
                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:2086)
                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:2032)
                                                                   at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.execSQL(FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.java:240)
                                                                   at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomOpenHelper.createMasterTableIfNotExists(RoomOpenHelper.java:131)
                                                                   at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomOpenHelper.checkIdentity(RoomOpenHelper.java:107)
                                                                   at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomOpenHelper.onOpen(RoomOpenHelper.java:100)
                                                                   at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.onOpen(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:133)
                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:310)
                                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:194)
                                                                   at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:93)
                                                                   at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:54)
                                                                   at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase.query(RoomDatabase.java:193)
                                                                   at com.jpmc.appstore.db.AppItemDao_Impl$11.compute(AppItemDao_Impl.java:415)
                                                                   at com.jpmc.appstore.db.AppItemDao_Impl$11.compute(AppItemDao_Impl.java:401)
                                                                   at android.arch.lifecycle.ComputableLiveData$2.run(ComputableLiveData.java:87)
                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
                                                                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Its not always, it comes once or twice out of 10, but when it comes I need to uninstall app and install. It even comes on fresh install of app also.
I used 'fallbackToDestructiveMigration()' also but no help.

Want to understand root cause of it. It might be dangerous for me in production.

Comment: Are you manually closing your `RoomDatabase` anywhere?

Comment: No I am not closing RoomDB manually anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Room version 1.1.1-rc1 and things are working fine now.